# Return numerical values at the end of string - Presto SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to return the numerical values at the end of a string, in their own column.

Example - adfjdakfadkf || adfjadkfajd || adjfkad || dajlaj (123456789)

The numbers change in length throughout the table, so it would need to be dynamic.

I was using split to map with '(' and ')' as delimiters, but am having no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Be sure to accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`regexp_extract()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract) to achieve this. For example:

```sql
WITH data(c) AS (
    VALUES 'adfjdakfadkf || adfjadkfajd || adjfkad || dajlaj (123456789)'
) 
SELECT regexp_extract(c, '\((\d+)\)', 1) 
FROM data
```

produces:

```
   _col0
-----------
 123456789
(1 row)
```